# Is it possible to use .NET 4.6.1 for Xamarin on Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono, portable-class-library

I want to use .NET PCL library from a NuGet that target .Net 4.6.1 in Xamarin PLC project.

I can add it to the project, it will build fine. But, I cannot reference it in the project itself, it just doesn't allow because of .NET versions differences. The maximum version that I can set for my PCL projects is 4.5.

I can select 4.5.1 for example but it will jump back to 4.5 due to missing profiles for that version.

I was not able to find those profiles or update .NET Framework.

If I'm doing something completely dumb, please, tell me :)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using visual studio 2017, you need to go to the visual studio installer, and select a few more checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm using Mac, and on a Mac you don't have .Net framework, you have a Mono wrapper around it. So versions that available for Windows does not apply.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the mono tag. Maybe you should include those details in your question?